# Unit Testing in python and AssertionError: False != True

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertion

I am doing some unit testing in general in python. I get below mention AssertionError.  I want to check the temperature range that if it is less than 30 and greater than 25 , then code should pass, but it gives me error. I can't figure out where I am making mistake.

```
test_csv_read_data_headers (__main__.ParseCSVTest) ... ok
test_data_fuelConsumption (__main__.ParseCSVTest) ... ok
test_data_temperature (__main__.ParseCSVTest) ...FAIL
test_data_timestamp (__main__.ParseCSVTest) ... ok
```

======================================================================

### FAIL: test_data_temp (**main**.ParseCSVTest)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "try.py", line 36, in test_data_temperature
30 > ali > 25, True
AssertionError: False != True
```

---

```
Ran 4 tests in 0.014s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

the code is as follow for temperature portion where my test fails.

```
def test_data_temperature(self):                
    column = [row[0].split()[3] for row in read_data(self.data)[1:]]                      
    ali = column[0:4]
    print ali                          
    self.assertEqual(
            30 > ali > 25, True 
            )
```

I print data in ali and it is in form of a list

```
['25.8', '25.6', '25.8', '25.8']
```

I am confuse that how can I check range of this and make assertions so that it pass the test. If somebody give a tip or example. I will really grateful.

Comment: If it's a list, then indeed it is not true that it is between 30 and 25.

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing a list to an integer.

You need to compare each value individually (eg using the python builtin [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)). Try something like

```
self.assertTrue(all(30 > a > 25 for a in ali))
```

You could also check the `min` and `max` value of the list. Slightly (negligibly) worse performance wise (I think?) but would give you more information if/when the test fails.

```
self.assertTrue(max(ali) < 30)
self.assertTrue(min(ali) > 25)
```